How do two slashes in Terraform source work?
Here is my Terraform Karpenter module:
module "karpenter" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/karpenter"
  cluster_name = module.eks.cluster_name
  node_iam_role_additional_policies = {
    AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
  }
}

You can see source has two slashes between "aws" and "modules". I initially thought I made a mistake, however, it turns out two slashes work well.
The document also has two slash.
If I update to one slash and run terraform apply, it will actually throw error instead:
│ Error: Invalid module source address
│
│   on main.tf line 73, in module "karpenter":
│   73:   source       = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/modules/karpenter"
│
│ Terraform failed to determine your intended installation method for remote module package "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/modules/karpenter".
│
│ If you intended this as a path relative to the current module, use "./terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/modules/karpenter" instead. The "./" prefix indicates that the address is a relative filesystem path.
╵

This is folder structure of .terraform after I run terraform init:

For curiosity, could someone help explain how does this path with two slashes work in the source? Thanks!

Does this answer your question? Why Git URL path part is separated by double slash //

The use of double slashes (//) in the Terraform module source path references subdirectories within a module repository. Let me attempt explaining this in the best way possible.
Terraform allows module source addresses to take different forms:

Local paths
Git repositories
Terraform Registry modules

To specify a subdirectory within a Terraform Registry module or Git repository, use // in the source path:
source = "<module-source>//<subdirectory>"

In your case:
source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/karpenter"


terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws points to the module on the Terraform Registry.
//modules/karpenter tells Terraform to use the karpenter subdirectory within that module.

Using a single slash (/) leads to an error:
source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/modules/karpenter"

This error occurs because Terraform interprets this as a local relative path, not a subdirectory in the Registry module, resulting in an invalid module source address error.
After running terraform init, Terraform stores modules in:

.terraform/modules/

This directory reflects the module paths specified in your configuration.
To wrap it all up, using // correctly directs Terraform to subdirectories within remote module repositories, avoiding path interpretation issues. For more details, check the Terraform documentation on modules in package sub-directories.
Hope this helps.
